# Drop down list not continuously updating as expected

Tags: c#

I would expect when I user clicks on a different selection that it would update. However it does not. Instead I have to click the button to reload the page to do so. I am unsure of why this is or how to solve it.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ucost = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        ttbox.Text = ucost.ToString();
    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ttbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: First verify that event handlers are correcly mapped to control events in your form designer (the fact that the DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChange1 handler name end by 1 indicate that you disconnected at least one handler and regenerated a second one from the form designer). Secondly please be more explicit on what action not continuously update what (maybe the not working code can also help to understand your intent)

Comment: Is your dropdown's autopostback property is set to true?